# Launch eset libc library before samba daemon

Tags: 14.04, samba, samba4, preload

Trying to configure "On-access scanner using preload LIBC library" in ESET File Security.

The manual states:

> ... to have the On-access scanner to monitor all file system access events immediately after starting 
>   the Samba server. Within the Samba daemon initialization script (`/etc/init.d/smb`), we would replace the statement
>
> ```
> daemon /usr/sbin/smbd $SMBDOPTIONS
> ```
>
> with the following line:
>
> ```
> LD_PRELOAD=@LIBDIR@/libesets_pac.so daemon /usr/sbin/smbd $SMBDOPTIONS
> ```

But I do not have a file /etc/init.d/smb, but there is /etc/init.d/smbd.

Can anyone tell me where to inscribe this line that would LIBC library was launched before the start of samba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the depths of `/etc/init.d/smbd` you'll find the following line which is what is actually launching `smbd`:

```
if ! start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --exec /usr/sbin/smbd -- -D; then
```

The [popular idea](https://serverfault.com/questions/128389/can-start-stop-daemon-use-environmental-variables) for passing through an environment variable is with `env` so you'd end up with:

```
if ! start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --exec /usr/bin/env LD_PRELOAD=@LIBDIR@/libesets_pac.so /usr/sbin/smbd -- -D; then
```

Note that I expect they want you to replace `@LIBDIR@` with the correct path to `libesets_pac.so`.

---

An alternative is creating a new launcher for `smbd` as `/usr/local/sbin/smbd`:

```
#!/bin/sh

LD_PRELOAD=@LIBDIR@/libesets_pac.so /usr/sbin/smbd
```

And then just alter `/etc/init.d/smbd` to call `/usr/local/sbin/smbd`.